# nginx: How can I remove port from url?

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I have a `vps` server and `domain`

## Nginx

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject** and **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location /static/ {
    root /home/myproject;
  }
  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
  }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
...
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;
}
```

`nginx -t` - `successful`

`systemctl status nginx` - `active`

**ufw status**

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When I open ip of `vps-server` in browser I get *home page of `nginx`*.

---

## gunicorn

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/myproject
ExecStart=/home/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
--access-logfile - \
--workers 3 \
--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
myproject.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# cat /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

`systemctl status gunicorn` - `active`

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi` - working

`/run/gunicorn.sock` - exists

---

## Django

**/home/myproject/myproject/.settings.py**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', 'localhost']

DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': 'test_db',
         'USER': 'test_user',
         'PASSWORD': 'test',
         'HOST': 'localhost',
         'PORT': '',
     }
}
```

I'm run a `manage.py runserver example.com:8000` and get response from `Django`, that the server is started on `example.com:8000`.

I'm open web-site by url `http://example.com:8000`

How can I open web site by url `http://example.com` (without `port`)

Comment: After configuring Nginx successfully it work. You don't need the port.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam ok. I'm wite `./manage.py runserver` and get response that server started on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. When I try open `example.com` I get `404` error

Comment: @At the `nginx` log I get `"/usr/share/nginx/html/admin/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: ***, server: localhost, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"`

Comment: by default browser for http request with no port will try on port 80. So if your app is not running on port 80 or you dont have anything to map port 80 to port 8000 then you will need to give port number in the URL

Comment: @ChrisDoyle How can I fix it?

Comment: Test your Nginx configuration for syntax errors by typing:

sudo nginx -t

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam test for `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` - is successful

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук You set up your project first then post your error log.  [http://example.com] use for testing.

Comment: The error log states `server: localhost`, but the example in your question uses `server_name example.com;`, so the request is not reaching the `server` block in your question. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view your entire configuration across all included files and identify why your `server` block and `server_name` is not matching the `host:` value in the error log.

Comment: @RichardSmith https://dpaste.de/AS5C

Comment: Ok, so no files are being included from the `sites-enabled` directory. Nginx is looking for files that match `.../sites-enabled/*.*` and your project file does not contain a `.` in its filename.

Comment: @RichardSmith Very thnx. It's worked... I'm stupid(

Answer (score 1):

you need create named location like

```
upstream serv {
    server unix:/app/tmp/unicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 80 ;
    root /usr/html ;
    try_files $uri/index.html $app ;

location @app {
    proxy_pass http://serv ;
}
}
```